# android Gridview shift one column

Tags: android, gridview, shift

I need to implement shifted column in gridview looks like this

[image]

but only with two columns. 
I have tried two use different types in adapter, but it have not solved my task
[image]

it seems to me that I will have to extend gridview and ovverride onDraw method but maybe already exists another solutions or libraries?

Comment: Use a `GridLayout`. It allows for non-uniform grids. It can be used on older devices, too, through the import of the support library.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through Layout XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"        
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```